# Laplace equation in polar coordinates with complex boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

My attempt to this question was setting $T''-\lambda T=0$ and try $\lambda=0$, $>0$ and $<0$. However, I do not seem to have sufficient information to determine which cases have non-trivial solutions ( since I just know $T(\theta)=-T(-\theta)$ ). Also, what does the information "periodic in $\theta$ with period $2 \pi$" imply in this question?

Comment: What does $T'' - \lambda T = 0$ have to do with the problem?  If you consider solutions of the type $f_n(r)\sin(n\theta)$ then you get a second order linear ODE for $f_n(r)$ in the variable $r$.  The ODE is not $f''(r) -\lambda f(r)=0$, it is something different (what is $\lambda$ anyway?)  You can look for solutions of the correct ODE in the form $r^{\alpha}$ for some parameter $\alpha$.  You will find two choice of possible $\alpha$, but you can eliminate one.

Comment: By Fourier theory, you can construct any odd function of $\theta$ of period $2\pi$, call it $u(2,\theta)$, as $u(2,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n \sin(n\theta)$ for some coefficients $C_n$, which can be taken as $C_n=B_n2^{-n}$. So you can construct solutions with any desired boundary condition for $u(2,\theta)$.

Comment: You should not forget to also consider with the condition $u(r,\theta)=u(r,\theta+2\pi)$ for the statement in the question "periodic in $\theta$ with period $2\pi$" .

Answer (score 1):

Consider $T(\theta)=a_1\sin\lambda\theta+a_2\cos\lambda\theta$

$T(\theta)=-T(-\theta)$ :

$a_1\sin\lambda\theta+a_2\cos\lambda\theta=-a_1\sin(-\lambda\theta)-a_2\cos(-\lambda\theta)$

$a_1\sin\lambda\theta+a_2\cos\lambda\theta=a_1\sin\lambda\theta-a_2\cos\lambda\theta$

$2a_2\cos\lambda\theta=0$

$a_2=0$

$\therefore T(\theta)=a_1\sin\lambda\theta$

$T(\theta)=T(\theta+2\pi)$ :

$a_1\sin\lambda\theta=a_1\sin(\lambda(\theta+2\pi))$

$\lambda=n$ , $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore$ Let $u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(r,n)\sin n\theta$ ,

Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\partial^2C(r,n)}{\partial r^2}\sin n\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial C(r,n)}{\partial r}\sin n\theta-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n^2C(r,n)}{r^2}\sin n\theta=0$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{\partial^2C(r,n)}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial C(r,n)}{\partial r}-\dfrac{n^2C(r,n)}{r^2}\right)\sin n\theta=0$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial^2C(r,n)}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial C(r,n)}{\partial r}-\dfrac{n^2C(r,n)}{r^2}=0$

$C(r,n)=A_nr^n+B_nr^{-n}$

$\therefore u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_nr^n\sin n\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_nr^{-n}\sin n\theta$